# I set the depth for the camera, but it will be rendered first

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5.4.1f1.
There are multiple cameras on the scene and there is camera I would like to draw last for post effects.
But whatever value I set for the depth of the camera,
That camera will be rendered first on Profiler.
Therefore, the rendered object is not displayed.
How can I change the rendering order?

Comment: Bigger value is later rendered. You need to set your last camera with a depth value bigger than the others cameras, including main camera.

Comment: I set a larger depth value to a post-effect camera with than all the other cameras. But it will be rendered first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. When `Camera.targetTexture` set, then render first.